# IF Spectrum is inverted

Tags: frequency-spectrum

The dechirp-on-receive procedure returns near-range at a higher IF frequency than the returns from the far-range. How do I invert this spectrum so that near-range returns appear at a lower IF frequency than far-range returns?

I have attached a plot where the y-axis refers to the azimuth-time and the x-axis refers to the range-frequency

[image]

**Edit:**
I am making use of python to generate the IF signal. This single pulse is used to generate a 2D matrix of IF signals. Is there a way that forces the near-range targets to appear at a lower frequency and vice-versa?

The plot above is the resultant of the range Fourier transform on the signal matrix.

```
def ifSignalPulseD(T,Tp,Rt,Ro,Fc,Cr):
    # Description: 
    # creates a single receive pulse 
    
    # Input:  T , Time
    #         Tp, Pulse width   
    #         Rt, Target distance  
    #         Ro, Reference distance 
    #         Fc, Center Frequency  
    #         Cr, Chirp rate      
    # Output: if, Mixed Signal Pulse
    
    Tdt = timeDelay(Rt) # Time delay wrt to Target distance
    Tdr = timeDelay(Ro) # Time delay wrt to Reference distance

    phase = np.exp(-1j*(4*PI*Cr * (Fc/Cr + T - (2*Ro/C)) * (Rt - Ro)) / C) *  np.exp(1j*(4*PI*Cr*((Rt - Ro)**2))/(C**2))
    
    return rect(T,Tp,Tdt) * phase
```

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to give us more context.  What radio are you using?  If it's an SDR with a hardware front-end, please tell us about both.  If it's an SDR that you've written, please give us a block diagram of the algorithm (i.e., show it to us as if it were a radio block diagram).

Comment: hi @TimWescott its a python implementation. I think I have figured out on how to invert the frequencies. I did a conjugation in the time domain so that it would reverse the frequency spectrum. Although I am not 100% confident with my current solution. However, this looks like to be way to reverse the frequencies such that the near-range appears at a lower frequency whereas the far-range appears at a higher frequency.